# Json, JPA, ManytoOne and OneToMany => recursive

Tags: java, json, jpa, eclipselink

I've tried to read all the Qs about this topic and still there is something I'm missing.

**My problem is: that the two tables KIDS and PARENT are calling eachother recursivly**

I've got an EJB asking for a Parent with an id, - I've (I think) used @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent") where needed. The result could be better: When asking for the parent (with an id) it that sees there is a kid that take the parent that ask for the kid... (in an almost never ending story :)

**JSON OUTPUT**

```html
{
  "parentsid": 1,
  ...
  "parentsusername": null,
  "calendars": [],
  "kids": [
    {
      "kidsid": 2,
        ...
      "parent": {
        "parentsid": 1,
        ...
        "calendars": [],
        "kids": [
          {
            "kidsid": 2,               
            "calendars": [],
            "checkins": [],
            "parent": {
              "parentsid": 1,                 
              "calendars": [],
              "kids": [
                {
                  "kidsid": 2,                     
                  "calendars": [],    
                 .....
```

**The Classes**
I've got a Stateless Bean calling:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/checkin")
public class CheckinService {

 @PersistenceContext(unitName="chkin",type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
 EntityManager entityManager;

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/{id}")    
public Parent read(@PathParam("id") int id) {
    Parent parent = entityManager.find(Parent.class, id);        
    return parent;
}
```

The Entity classes are made the following way with

```
/**
 * The persistent class for the KIDS database table.
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="KIDS")
@NamedQuery(name="Kid.findAll", query="SELECT k FROM Kid k")
public class Kid implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="KIDSID")
    private int kidsid;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Calendar
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="kid")
    private List<Calendar> calendars;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Checkin
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="kid")
    private List<Checkin> checkins;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Parent
    @ManyToOne             **// <=============**
    @JoinColumn(name="parentsId")
    private Parent parent;
}
```

Entity call for Parents:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENTS")
@NamedQuery(name="Parent.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Parent p")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="PARENTSID")
    private int parentsid;

    ...

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Calendar
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
    private List<Calendar> calendars;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Kid
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent") **// <=============**
    private List<Kid> kids;
```

**The Database look like this:**
Two database Tables one named PARENTS and one KIDS there is a onetomany from PARENTS to KIDS with a foreng key called FK-KIDS_parentsID

```
PARENTS ==========FK_KIDS_parentsId==========< KIDS
(PK) PARENTSID                                 (PK) KIDSID
                                               (FK) parentsId
```

**Stacktrace**

```
[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(JI[I[I[IJ)I+0
j  sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll()I+43
j  sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(Lsun/nio/ch/WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector;)I+1
j  sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(J)I+63
j  sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(J)I+37
j  sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(J)I+30
j  sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select()I+2
j  org.xnio.nio.SelectorUtils.await(Lorg/xnio/nio/NioXnio;Ljava/nio/channels/SelectableChannel;I)V+23
j  org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.awaitWritable()V+26
j  org.xnio.conduits.AbstractSinkConduit.awaitWritable()V+7
j  io.undertow.conduits.ChunkedStreamSinkConduit.awaitWritable()V+7
j  org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.awaitWritable()V+4
j  io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.awaitWritable()V+20
j  io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$WriteDispatchChannel.awaitWritable()V+20
j  org.xnio.channels.Channels.writeBlocking(Ljava/nio/channels/GatheringByteChannel;[Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;II)J+34
j  io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write([BII)V+311
j  org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletResponseWrapper$DeferredOutputStream.write([BII)V+15
j  org.jboss.resteasy.util.CommitHeaderOutputStream.write([BII)V+11
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._flushBuffer()V+24
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._writeBytes([B)V+17
J 1041 C2 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V (185 bytes) @ 0x0000000002979c78 [0x00000000029796c0+0x5b8]
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V+41
J 1041 C2 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V (185 bytes) @ 0x0000000002979b78 [0x00000000029796c0+0x4b8]
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V+41
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(Ljava/util/List;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V+163
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V+7
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V+34
J 1041 C2 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V (185 bytes) @ 0x0000000002979b78 [0x00000000029796c0+0x4b8]
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V+41
J 1041 C2 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V (185 bytes) @ 0x0000000002979b78 [0x00000000029796c0+0x4b8]
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V+41
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(Ljava/util/List;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V+163
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V+7
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V+34
J 1041 C2 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V (185 bytes) @ 0x0000000002979b78 [0x00000000029796c0+0x4b8]
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V+41
J 1041 C2 com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V (185 bytes) @ 0x0000000002979b78 [0x00000000029796c0+0x4b8]
j  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(Ljava/lang/Object;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator;Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider;)V+41
```

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with JPA. The problem is with how the entities are serialized. Add the necessary annotations to avoid serializing what you don't want. (@JsonIgnore for example, if using Jackson)

Comment: and the stack trace of that recursive calling would tell you what starts it off ... i.e is it JSON, or is it JPA, or something else?

Comment: @JBNizet your one to something, - I would not have figure that one out myself, - I'll comeback

Comment: @NeilStockton Found in  pid.log, - because the server crashes :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the comments indicate, this doesn't seem to be so much a JPA issue as it is a JSON serialization issue. Fortunately, Jackson provides [several annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#object-references-identity) to deal with this sort of situation.

Use [`@JsonManagedReference`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonManagedReference.html) on the parent and [`@JsonBackReference`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonBackReference.html) on the child, and you may want to try playing with [`@JsonIdentityInfo`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIdentityInfo.html).

Here's some [more reading](http://keenformatics.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-solve-json-infinite-recursion.html) you may find helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with Circular dependencies and JSON serialization, an easy way to solve this would be to use `@JsonIdentityInfo` on both classes, you should have something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="KIDS")
@NamedQuery(name="Kid.findAll", query="SELECT k FROM Kid k")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Kid implements Serializable {
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENTS")
@NamedQuery(name="Parent.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Parent p")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
```

This way you ensure that in each kid serialization the parent won't be serialized but you'll get only his id instead.

Comment: Thanks I'll trye this, the funny thing is that I returned to the problem yesterday :D

Answer (score 0):

@dcsohl thank you for your help, - I think I got it now...

I returned to my problem, and had another go at this. It's JSON recursiv problem.

Instead I'm using @XmlTransient I found another way of dealing with this problem, - the problem with XMLTransient is that you do NOT get the id, - so instead I'm using: [@XmlIDREF](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlIDREF.html) and [@XmlID](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlID.html) to solve this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENTS")
@NamedQuery(name="Parent.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Parent p")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="PARENTSID")
    @XmlAttribute @XmlID private int parentsid;

    ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="PARENTS_KIDS",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name ="PARENT_FK"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "KID_FK"))     
    private List<Kid> kids;
```

Class Kids

```
@Entity
@Table(name="KIDS")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name="Kid.findAll", query="SELECT k FROM Kid k"),
}) 
@XmlRootElement
public class Kid implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="KIDSID")
private int kidsid;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="kids")
@XmlAttribute @XmlIDREF private List<Parent> parents;

....
}
```

And it works :D

Comment: @JBNizet I might do, - but I don't know that, - I've taken the Jboss straight out of the box and not included any other libraries, - because I want to use the standard. If I'm using the  JsonIgnore I get a compiler error. But well now it works, - thanks for you help